# Integração de duas aplicações diferentes em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, eu preciso integrar duas aplicações distintas: uma é uma aplicação de administração do negócio do cliente e a outra uma aplicação de gestão financeira.

São duas aplicações separadas, então o que preciso é que, ao cadastrar um cliente na aplicação de administração, esse cliente seja integrado na aplicação financeira em tempo real.

O que já pensei:

Como as aplicações foram desenvolvidas em Asp.Net e seguindo os conceitos de DDD e consigo pegar as DLLs do `services` e referenciá-las na outra aplicação, também referencio a DLL do *Model* e assim eu posso criar um objeto cliente da aplicação financeira, acessar o método e adicionar utilizando a lógica da regra de negócios dela.

Só que não sei se isso é a melhor maneira. Já pensei em integrar dessa forma utilizando DLLs, já pensei em fazer por Web API que no *controller* eu fizesse uma chamada para a API de integração passando um JSON.

Também pensei em fazer um programa integrador que tivesse um *time* e que fizesse esta integração realizando `selects` e `inserts` de tempo em tempo.

Gostaria da opinião de vocês. Devo usar apenas a camada de serviço do DDD? Devo usar Web API? Ou alguma outra abordagem?

Qual a vantagem e desvantagem de cada uma?

Comment: Qual a escala de utilização dos serviços? quantos usuários? quantas requisições? Quantas pessoas trabalham no desenvolvimento desses duas aplicações? Você prevê que haverá muitas modificações nessas aplicações no futuro? Elas rodam servidores diferentes ou usam o mesmo? O banco de dados é único ou particionado?  O que você quer dizer com "tempo real"? 10ms, 50ms, 1s? Acho que a resposta depende de todas essas perguntas e talvez outras.

Answer (score 1):

> Só que não sei se isso é a melhor maneira. Já pensei em integrar dessa forma utilizando DLLs, já pensei em fazer por Web API que no *controller* eu fizesse uma chamada para a API de integração passando um JSON.

Há várias vantagens em fazer isto internamente. Como suas aplicações já possuem uma camada intermediária comum entre elas, basta referenciar a DLL e usar.

A abordagem por Web API é interessante se a integração for por um serviço ou aplicação que você não tenha controle sobre o código. Fora isso, a alternativa mais coesa é sempre a melhor.

> Também pensei em fazer um programa integrador que tivesse um *time* e que fizesse esta integração realizando `selects` e `inserts` de tempo em tempo.

Esta alternativa não é boa porque você não tem disponibilidade de dados em tempo real. Terá de esperar seu serviço integrador executar para ter as informações disponíveis.

---

#### Outro padrão de design

Há um terceiro padrão de design que é interessante mencionar, e que seria o melhor para o seu caso, que é fazer uma aplicação ler o contexto de dados da outra, mas isso só teria validade se você faz isso do Entity Framework.

Como na sua resposta você já disse que possui uma camada de serviço que faz isso por você, significa que não existe esta preocupação de mapeamento, já que a aplicação toda está com o domínio de dados integrado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

Como as aplicações já estão prontas e rodando, acredito que o melhor a fazer seria utilizar Web API, criando um método em cada aplicação que seria chamado para inserir um usuário. Quando um usuário fosse criado em uma das aplicações, essa aplicação chamaria o método da outra aplicação com os dados desse novo cliente, e dessa forma as duas aplicações estariam integradas. Essa parece ser a solução mais simples e rápida, mas você precisaria fazer algum trabalho manual para sincronizar os clientes já cadastrados.

Outra opção seria utilizar uma base de dados integrada. Dessa forma, a tabela que armazena as informações sobre o cliente poderia ser compartilhada entre as duas aplicações. Mas isso exigiria uma reestruturação na arquitetura atual das aplicações.

Já se você quiser que o usuário faça um único login para ter acesso às duas aplicações, você poderia utilizar uma base da dados comum para realizar a autenticação dos usuários. Dessa forma, um usuário precisaria se autenticar apenas uma vez e poderia acessar diversas aplicações. Cada aplicação continuaria funcionando de forma independente, e a sessão do usuário garantiria que ele está autenticado. Essa solução exigiria um esforço ainda maior para adaptar a arquitetura atual, mas poderia ser muito positivo para a experiência do usuário poder acessar todas as aplicações fazendo apenas uma autenticação.

A decisão final é sua, mas espero ter ajudado.